# Query two tables for different/separate values

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

task
id   name   dueDate   completed   projectID

project
id   name   dueDate   completed

I need to query both tables for rows with the same data. I tried doing a sample statement just looking for rows with completed=0, but never got any results. I think it has to do with using OR instead of AND, but it's just a little above my level right now...Any ideas?

TO CLARIFY, I'm not looking for duplicate rows, I'm looking for 'all tasks and projects with completed = 0'

The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM "task" t, "project" p WHERE t.dueDate = "2012-08-17" OR p.dueDate = "2012-08-17" AND t.completed = 0 OR p.completed = 0
```

---

I did manage to get one of the answers' code to work, however I realized that my entire app was written to talk to one table, and that it would be much easier to just combine the task and project table and use an `isProject` column to differentiate projects from tasks. This also adds the ability to nest projects inside of projects, because projects will now have a `projectID` column as well.

In the end, KISS prevails...

Thanks for all the help! I will mark the answer that worked, even though I won't be using it.

Comment: Could you post the query you tried?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM "task" t, "project" p WHERE t.dueDate = "2012-08-17" OR p.dueDate = "2012-08-17" AND t.completed = 0 OR p.completed = 0`

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Using `"` for table identifiers seems odd. Are you sure you're not intending to use `\`` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT dueDate, completed
FROM task AS t 
WHERE (dueDate = "2012-08-17" AND completed = 0)
UNION ALL
SELECT dueDate, completed
FROM project AS p
WHERE (dueDate = "2012-08-17" AND completed = 0)
```

This should give you all records from each table where `dueDate = "2012-08-17"` and `completed = 0`.

Comment: this works! now to figure out how to change this code to make that statement...ugh: `$where = '(t.'.$range.' OR p.'.$range.') AND (t.'.$status.' OR p.'.$status.')';`

Comment: so will this work if i take the columns out (dueDate, completed) and just use * to work with my existing prepared statement? [edit] just tried using *s, and got `#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`

Comment: Couldn't hurt to try!  I think the columns between the two tables need to overlap in the query but I might be wrong.

Comment: Ok so this works as is, however it doesn't return the whole row, it only returns dueDate and completed. Not sure how to adjust, asides from adding in the other columns I need after the SELECT statements

Answer (score 1):

Try using parenthesis.

```
SELECT * FROM "task" t, "project" p WHERE (t.dueDate = "2012-08-17" OR p.dueDate = "2012-08-17") AND (t.completed = 0 OR p.completed = 0)
```

Comment: phpmyadmin: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"task" t, "project" p WHERE (t.dueDate = "2012-08-17" OR p.dueDate = "2012-08-17' at line 1`

Comment: Yeah, what Zane said ... Sorry.  That's what I get for copying and pasting.

Answer (score 1):

If You want only values matches from both tables with completed=0 from dueDate='2012-08-17':

You can use join to bound that tables results into one.
Inner join will return only results which matches on both sides.
So You can use it to match them in both tables by it and then filter for Your wanted value by classic where:

```
select * from task t inner join project p on t.dueDate = p.dueDate and t.completed = p.completed
where t.dueDate = '2012-08-17' and t.completed = 0
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join project p on t.dueDate = p.dueDate and t.completed = p.completed wher' at line 1